# Make input form invisible

Tags: css, html, forms, input

I have input form that displayed over background text images.
i want the input forms to be invisible so the user can insert the input but a white blank form won't be displayed,only the background.
i tried "transparent" property but its covers both the form and the background text image.
you can see on the images here how it is now and in the other image how i want it to be.
thanks.
**this is how i have it now:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLKYT.jpg
**and this is how i want it:**
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VJOnf.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You can make the elements transparent:

```
form *{
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

Note: this will apply it to all elements inside a form, you'd need to modify your selector accordingly to what you have/want

Comment: yes thats what i did there in the 1st form on the uploaded image which made the form and the image transparent.

Comment: Then what is the problem?

Comment: i want the text image to be seen, check the second image i added in my post . now i have white field there.

Comment: You should only make the background-color transparent and set the border to none. That way your text will still be shown. Have you tried the code from my answer?

Comment: i did, same result as i had.

Comment: Can you post a jsFiddle so I can see what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I just tried Kenneth's solution on IE5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, Chrome, Safari, FF, and Opera. All worked.

What browser are you using? Can you provide a live example?

Answer (score 0):

```
input[type=text],
textarea {
    background: transparent;
    border: none;
}

/* This if you don't want an outline on focus - bad for accessibility */
input[type=text]:focus,
textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```